# Material UI selected Tab styling

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I am trying to apply styling via styled components to a Material UI Tab component when it has a selected prop value of true, but I'm not having any luck. According to the Material UI API [documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/tab/), the Tab component will gain a css class when the selected prop has a true value, which it does, but none of the styling that I'm trying to apply to that css class is actually being applied.

Tab component:

```
const StyledTab = styled(({ ...props }) => (
  <Tab {...props} classes={{ selected: "selected" }} />
))`
  & .selected {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
`;
```

Application:

```
function StyledComponentsTab() {
  return (
    <div>
      <StyledTab label="test" selected />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/5mw96nm56x)

Answer (score 0):

The style isn't being applied because you need to override the library's style via `!important`. It should look like `background-color: yellow !important;`.

Also your `.selected` css rule doesn't apply to the component because the `selected` text on your component is an  `attribute` not a `class`. The `.selected` rule applies to html elements with `className="selected"`.

Here is your code example with the style applied: https://codesandbox.io/s/72o992lv36

Comment: yes, I realize that is an attribute, but you can specify the name of the selected class when defining the component. If you inspect the tab element, it will have a class name "selected". Also, the !important addition has no effect on the class styling.

Comment: In that case you can use `&.selected { background-color: yellow; }` and the style applies as wanted. The difference is `& .selected` applies to child elements within the `<StyledTab/>` implementation, instead of the top-level element which is what you want.

Comment: Happy to help :)